# Is there a way to measure ATP usage in the brain similarly to fMRI?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, bioenergetics

Is there a way to measure ATP usage in the brain (or anywhere else) similarly to how fMRI works (measuring changes in iron resonance in oxygenated/deoxygenated blood)? Is there some sort of similar signal that can be used for ATP?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this doesn't exist. If it did, that would be awesome.

The following is 100% pure speculation with nothing to back this up at all (as a disclaimer).

Phosphorus-31 (the stable isotope) is NMR active, which means that you could theoretically use an MRI machine to visualize phosphorus. A quick google search shows scientists attempting to use phosphorus MRI for [visualizing bone structure](http://www.pnas.org/content/early/2012/03/12/1117293109.abstract?sid=96fad806-6097-413d-af31-bed001ea5804http://www.pnas.org/content/early/2012/03/12/1117293109.abstract?sid=96fad806-6097-413d-af31-bed001ea5804).

I don't really know much about MRI, but I do know some about small molecule NMR, which is based on the same principles. This is a pretty cool paper showing phosphorus-31 NMR used to [measure ATP synthesis](http://www.pnas.org/content/97/12/6880).

Maybe in the distant future it could be possible to use phosphorus-31 MRI to visualize ATP/ADP ratios in various tissues, including the brain. But that would be some amazing sci-fi stuff.